# Should "load edits" load all pending edits for the page?

Tags: feature-request, edits, live-refresh

When you have been on a page for a long time and there is an edit to the question and one or more answers. Shouldn't the page load all pending edits when you click the grey bar that appears? Not for every question/answer that has an edit.

Hope that makes sense? I can add an example if not.

Comment: If you use the [Official keyboard shortcuts](http://stackapps.com/q/2567) script, using the `F` key loads all pending changes for both the question and the answers.

Comment: I just refresh the page if there are a lot of edits since I loaded the page.

Comment: @Servy Personally, I would prefer the ajax call over the full page postback which is probably not needed in this case (again, don't know the current implementation)

Comment: @StuartBlackler When it's just a small section, sure, when it's several posts, probably comments as well, voting changes, and so on it's enough that I'd just as soon reload the page.  On top of that, if there are that many edits, it likely means that the content which isn't automatically updated via ajax is quite out of date.

Comment: @Servy, I agree, but what if you are half way writing through an answer?

Comment: @StuartBlackler It saves answers as drafts ;)  And for those that just don't trust it, there's the clipboard.

Comment: @Servy thanks, didn't know that :)

Answer (score 4):

This feature already exists, and even has its own mapped key on your keyboard: <kbd>F5</kbd>